# libusb not working with mediatek chipset

Tags: android, libusb

I have an android application to take videos and pictures from USB camera. When I tested the application in many devices branded Samsung, Motorola, Nexus, Lenovo. The applocation working well and good in most of the devices with variety of cameras. The problem is I am not getting frames from camera in Mediatek chipset devices [Mobile, Tablets]. I found that, libusb is able to talk to the connected camera. It is correctly getting the descriptors, resolutions, formats but giving 0 byts when I try to read frames. I am using low resolutions, say 640 X 480 with 30fps. I would like know whether Mediatek chipset supports getting data from USB cameras.

I have tried with Control trasfers, Bulk trasfer & Isochronous transfers.

I would like to know, what trasfer types does Mediatekchipset supports.
What is the max data that it can transfer from USB port?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, were you finally able to find a solution to this? or at least have found any other hints?